# Adding multiple GeoTIFF files to a GeoPackage TABLE

Tags: windows, sqlite, gdal, geotiff

How can this be done?  Currently, I'm trying this command ...

> C:_gdal>gdal_translate.exe a.tif empty.gpkg -of gpkg -co
>   RASTER_TABLE=table1

... which succeeds

but when I try to add another file to the SAME TABLE ...

> C:_gdal>gdal_translate.exe b.tif empty.gpkg -of gpkg -co
>   RASTER_TABLE=table1 -co APPEND_SUBDATASET=YES

I get an error, "ERROR 1: Raster table table1 not correctly initialized due to missing call to SetGeoTransform()"

Am I just doing this completely wrong?  How can I add multiple files to the same table?

Comment: Hack: create a bunch of tables and merge them with SQL. GeoPackage is just a SQLite database.

Comment: @lusitanica So make each GeoTIFF it's own table, then make each of those tables an entry in one table, is what you're saying?  That leads me to another question, what is the point of using GeoPackage at all if it's just an SQLite database?  I mean, is the only benefit that table names are standardized?

Comment: Even though it may be internally a database with standardized geospatial metadata, it should not be treated as such, that's why I said it was a hack. The error you're getting means a geotransformation matrix has not been set with SetGeoTransform() This is effectively needed to determine the zoom level of the full resolution dataset based on the pixel resolution, dataset and tile dimensions. But if the geotiffs are parts of the same mosaic the hack could work. Note: SetGeoTransform() is available via API, there's no equivalent option in gdal_translate.